# Python - DPI metadata is coordinates

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a python script that gets the meta data of a file and puts it into a txt file. The script works and i got it from [Here](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extracting-image-metadata-in-python). My oly issue with itis that the DPI is shown as a coordinate and not a integer.

It looks like this `(300,300)` and I would like it to look like this: `300`.

Here is my script as I have it:

```
image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

    # extract other basic metadata
    info_dict = {
        "FileName": os.path.basename(image.filename),
        "FileSize": os.path.getsize(image.filename),
        "FilePath": pathlib.Path(image.filename).suffix,
        "DPI": image.info['dpi'],
        "Height": image.height,
        "Width": image.width,
        "Format": image.format,
        "Mode": image.mode,
        "Frames": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
    }

    line = ""
    for label in range (1):
        line += f"'{str(label)}'"
       
        line = ",".join([str(val) for val in info_dict.values()])
        print(line)
```

Comment: My understanding is this: "300 DPI" is actually just shorthand for "300 by 300 dots per inch"; usually the vertical and horizontal components are the same so there's no need to distinguish them. But it's possible the image's pixels are not square, and hence the DPI value can potentially be different horizontally versus vertically. So you're _probably_ safe just averaging those two values I'd think, or even just picking one arbitrarily. Maybe someone else with more confident knowledge can chime in.

Comment: That does make sense on why it is, however the idea here is to take this data and put it into a SQL table, and I was asked to make it one value. the average would be good however I am not sure how to calculate that. I was wondering if there's a way to print out just one of them somehow

Comment: You don't know how to access individual items in a tuple? Sounds like you should study up on Python basics, that's a huge thing to not know. Anyway, `image.info['dpi'][0]` or `image.info['dpi'][1]` will give you either one of the values, and so the average would of coruse be `(image.info['dpi'][0] + image.info['dpi'][1]) / 2`.

Comment: dpi:
A tuple representing the reported pixel density in pixels per inch, if the file is a jfif file and the units are in inches. -- depending on the image format, the result has to be interpreted differently --
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#tiff

Comment: Thank you, I use java and C a lot this is one of my first python projects. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
info_dict = {
        "FileName": os.path.basename(image.filename),
        "FileSize": os.path.getsize(image.filename),
        "FilePath": pathlib.Path(image.filename).suffix,
        "DPI": image.info['dpi'][0],
        "Height": image.height,
        "Width": image.width,
        "Format": image.format,
        "Mode": image.mode,
        "Frames": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
    }
```